# SQL efficiency optimization, O(n^2) time complexity, how to simplify?

Tags: sql, database

```
insert into probclass (jobid, tag, probability) 
    (select s1.jobid, s1.tag, (select count(*) from sqlset as s2 
                             where s1.jobid = s2.jobid and s1.tag = s2.tag)
                            /
                            (select count(*) from sqlset as s3 
                             where s1.jobid = s3.jobid) 
     from sqlset as s1)
```

I'm new to SQL, but I'm trying to write a query as simple as possible. This is a simple query that calculate the probability of attr 'tag' with same 'jobid'. I know this is bad coding as the enumerator and numerator were redundantly calculated again and again (namely each time).

Is there any simple O(n) query out there? (By simple I mean not using many clauses like `WITH` etc..)

Comment: Are you using MySQL or MS SQL Server? (Please, don't tag products not involved.)

Comment: Isn't there an universally-compilable version for this specific query?

Comment: Probably there is, and if you want that answer the SQL tag is enough.

Comment: There is a simple(ish) answer if your database product supports windowed aggregates. [tag:sql-server] does, [tag:mysql] doesn't.

Comment: Maybe I'm confused abut your schema, but how is this query ever not returning a 1 for probability?  The numerator is `where s1.id = s2.id and s1.tag = s2.tag`.  Is `id` not your primary key?

Comment: Also, keep in mind that with SQL, time complexity is not entirely useful.  It's a declarative language, so the way you've written it does not necessarily indicate how the query engine will execute it.  Yes, joins and subqueries take time, but ultimately you still have to enumerate the sets to get a COUNT().  For SQL, you're going to want to compare the cost of execution plans more than anything.  You will find that subqueries will perform as fast or even faster than alternatives.

Comment: ok I changed it to jobid, it's not primary key. And the truth is, for this query, it takes forever.

Comment: The solution I figured out is to use a join..in clause.

Answer (score 0):

try to simply as

```
     select count(*) as 'count1' into #temp1 from sqlset as s2 
     where s1.id = s2.id and s1.tag = s2.tag
```

and

```
     select count(*) as 'count2' into #temp2 from sqlset as s3 
     where s1.id = s3.id
```

if both are different count value for different tables
then

```
     insert into probclass (id, tag, probability) 
    (select s1.id, s1.tag, (select count1 from #temp1/select count2 from #te,p2))
```